# Liquibase ошибка при запуске ChangeSet

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

При запуске без changeSet все взлетает.

Добавляю changeSet падает с ошибкой

```
    2022-02-08 14:38:58.157 ERROR 18772 --- [  restartedMain] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Change Set classpath:liquibase/db.changelog-1.0.xml::1.0.0::A.P. failed.  Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
      Position: 303 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.users (id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NULL, updated TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NULL, status VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'ACTIVE' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT USERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (username), UNIQUE (email))]
```

-application.properties

```
server.port=8080    
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_jwt3?serverTimezone=UTC
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=admin
    
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
    
    spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml
    spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_jwt3?serverTimezone=UTC
    spring.liquibase.user=postgres
    spring.liquibase.password=admin
```

- db.changelog-master.xml

```
      <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                                http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
            <include file="classpath:liquibase/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
        </databaseChangeLog>
```

- db.changelog-1.0.xml

```
    <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    
        <changeSet id="1.0.0" author="A.P.">
            <createTable tableName="users">
                <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="username" type="VARCHAR(100)">
                    <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="email" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                    <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="first_name" type="VARCHAR(100)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="last_name" type="VARCHAR(100)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="password" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="created" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="updated" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
                <column name="status" type="VARCHAR(25)" defaultValue="ACTIVE">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    
            </createTable>
        </changeSet>
    
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

-pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.10.7</jsonwebtoken.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.10.3</liquibase.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берём из текста ошибки запрос (`CREATE TABLE`) идём к самому postgresql и переспрашиваем. На что видим в ответ указатель на позицию

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...STAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NULL...
                                                             ^
```

Это действительно синтаксически некорректный default. У синтаксически корректного `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` нет скобок. Затем проверяем указанные листинги и находим пару

```
defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
```

Что скорей всего было написано человеком, а не как-то некорректно сгенерировано чем-то. Могу попробовать угадать, что литерал подставляется как есть и значение должно быть записано как

```
defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
```

Либо использовать `NOW()`

```
defaultValue="NOW()"
```